# Explicit form of Harnack's inequality

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions, laplacian

PDE text Evans defines Harnack's inequality for non-negative harmonic functions as
$$\sup_{B_{R}(0)}u\leq c \inf_{B_{R}(0)}u$$
where $c$ is a constant that only depends on the dimension $n$ such that an open ball $B_{R}(0)\subset \mathbb{R}^n$. Using this inequality is not hard to show that if $u$ is harmonic, non-negative for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^d$, then $u=0.$ By letting $M=\inf_{\mathbb{R}^n}u,$ we can define a new function $v=u-M$, which is non-neagtive and harmonic that saitisfies Harnack's inequality. Since $c$ is independent of $R$ we can take $R\rightarrow\infty$ to get that $u=0$.

But I also saw the following explicit form of Harnack's inequality

$$\frac{R^{d-2}(R-|x|)}{(R+|x|)^{d-1}}u(0)\leq u(x) \leq \frac{R^{d-2}(R+|x|)}{(R-|x|)^{d-1}}u(0)$$

and now I am wondering if the same result can be obtained from this form, by taking $R\rightarrow \infty$, is this justified?

Comment: It seems perfectly correct. What could go wrong? Just any constant function is harmonic on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Thus, you should only conclude that $u$ is constant.

Comment: @halbaroth Do you mean after taking $R\rightarrow \infty$ we get $u(0)\leq u(x)\leq u(0)$ and hence, $u$ is a constant function, but not necessarily zero?

Comment: Yes! In your proof, you get $v= 0 $ and not $u = 0$.